# Disk size issue in Linux lite running in VirtualBox and different information from different apps

Tags: hard-disk, virtual-machine

I have a VM running Linux Lite 5 for quite some time now. Recently I've been having disk space issues.

I have cleared as much as I can and I have also increased the size of the virtual disk in virtual box as you can see here:
[image]

In Linux lite in the Disks app I can see this:
[image]

It states that /dev/sda5 is 95% full but if I go into the command line and type `df -h` I see:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  2.9M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda5       158G  150G  859M 100% /
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       511M  8.0K  511M   1% /boot/efi
shared          953G  569G  385G  60% /home/acs/DevLinuxShared
tmpfs           1.6G   12K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

So here `/dev/sda5` is at 100% and not 95%.
Also note that there is no `/dev/sda2` here.

How can I fix this disk space issue?

I've increased the virtual disk to no avail and I've also deleted some files but that didn't do much.

Is there something in linux lite that I have to do so it can see the increased disk space?

Can I merge `/dev/sda2` as it seems it's not holding anything?

Edit:
I do have gparted installed, this is what I see when I open it up:
[image]
I still don't see any more space even though I did increase the size in VirtualBox

Comment: `Can I merge /dev/sda2 as it seems it's not holding anything?` no, it's holding sda5 - it's an extended partition ... what you need to do is extend sda2, since you've made the disk bigger, then extend sda5 to use up the new space now available in sda2, then resize the filesystem to use up the new space now available in sda5 - the most ironic thing is you use EFI with MBR disk partitioning

Comment: Not 100% sure how to extend sd2 but I'll google I guess.
Regarding the issue you mentioned with EFI, what should I have done? Is there a way to fix it? Maybe create an answer so I can accept it? Thanks

Comment: Oh, not saying it's a problem, just that GPT patitioning you wouldn't have this crazy extended partition with a partition inside it - do you have `gparted` - I think that will help you resize partitions, that's the trickiest (though not very tricky) part, the resize of the filesystem is the easiest part using `resize2fs` (don't worry, resize2fs can resize ext4 partitions)

Comment: `create an answer` ... what answer? you want me to answer your question based on an image of a partition layout and output of df? Sorry, not nearly enough information for me to give you any meaningful sort of answer

Comment: Apologies if there is not enough information, I'll try to provide whatever is missing.

Comment: @JaromandaX I have added the screenshot of gparted, hopefully this will provide more information, if not please let me know what I can do.